# Wrapping c++ and CUDA code with cython

Tags: python, c++11, cuda, cython

I want to wrap c++ and CUDA code with cython.
I looked npcuda-example (https://github.com/rmcgibbo/npcuda-example) and I change setup.py as follows.

```
ext = Extension('MyWrap',
            sources=['src/my_code.cu', 'python/my_wrap.pyx'],
            library_dirs=[CUDA['lib']],
            libraries=['cudart'],
            language='c++',
            runtime_library_dirs=[CUDA['lib']],
            # this syntax is specific to this build system
            # we're only going to use certain compiler args with nvcc and not with gcc
            # the implementation of this trick is in customize_compiler() below
            extra_compile_args={'clang++': ['-std=c++11','-O3'],
                                'nvcc': ['-std=c++11','-gencode','arch=compute_30,code=sm_30']},
            include_dirs = [numpy_include, CUDA['include'], 'src'],
            extra_link_args=["-std=c++11"])
```

And, I run setup.py for my code,
but, I have a nvcc error `"fatal error: 'mutex' file not found"`
I guess "-std=c++11" option can not pass nvcc compiler.
How can I wrap c++ and CUDA code include c++11 code?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why do you want that? For what do you need cython if you already have your high-performance code in C++ and CUDA?

Comment: Yes, I have C++ and CUDA code.
I want to make python interface of my code.

Comment: I solve this problem. I use mac os x and anaconda with pyenv.
distutils.util.get_platform() return mac os x 10.5. Then I change python anaconda to system default python, I can compile my code.

Comment: @nyatsui: If that is your solution, please add it as an answer (it is perfectly OK to answer your own questions)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for answering.
I solved this problem. Command "distutils.util.get_platform()" return mac os x 10.5 on my Mac. So I change python anaconda to system default python, I can compile c++11 code. But I can not compile my all code.
In accordance with Saullo Castro's answer, first I build my code to library using CUDA_ADD_LIBRARY of CMake CUDA Package. And I compile only wrapper.pyx with this library. Then I can wrap my c++ code with cython.
Thank you!!